# jqgrid - add or subtract value within grouped rows

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-php, jqgrid-formatter

FOr grouping summary, which gives sum of values of column , say as total.
For this, can we have a combo math operation based on another column value

---

### col1  |  col2 |

P    |   5   |
 R    |   2   |

### P    |   6   |

Total :  9 
I should add col2 values if Col1 = P and subtract value if its col2=R

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the implementation to have the columns as rows and grouped them by id
and used the

> `summaryType: mySum`

Also I used the

> formatter : intValueFormatter

for the column holding the numbers and in the custom function , i converted the numbers to positive / neagtive based on other column values ( as per my requirement )

And I got add/subtract math operations.

> function intValueFormatter(cellValue, opts, rowObject) {
>
> ```
>         switch (rowObject.a_cashflowtype) {
>             case  "ABC ":
>                 var newVal = parseFloat(cellValue) * -1;
>                 return parseFloat(newVal);
>                 break;
>             case  "XYZ" :
>                 return parseFloat(cellValue);
>                 break;
>         }
>     }
> ```